# Installing Linux on a tablet

Tags: linux, arm, distributions, tablet

I would like to install Linux on my tablet. It has Cortex A9 processor (RockChip RK2928), 512MB RAM and 4GB internal memory. My question is: is there any Linux distro that would work on it? I tried to google but didn't find anything that would help me. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zpwebsites.linuxonandroid

Comment: Check this guide http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Features/Convert-an-Android-Device-to-Linux

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

Maybe your tablet is on the list of supported devices

Answer (score 1):

If your tablet came with Android installed, the place to start looking is the [XDA site](http://forum.xda-developers.com/).  There are all sorts of patches and mods there, and, depending on the exact model of your tablet, somebody might have ported a Linux distro to it.  Some tablets even allow dual boot, others can't be modified at all (that is, there is no known way to root them).